# Glow Animation from state to state on ImageButton

Tags: android, animation, imagebutton, glow

I have an ImageButton which has two states (selected, not selected) and it changes the drawable using selector.

I researched to make a glow like effect I should use a AlphaAnimation, However when it starts from alpha=0, it makes the background visible and I dont want that.

I need to have something like having two images on top of each other and alpha animate just the top one.

How would I do that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_alpha"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```